# How to remove an object from an jsonarray based on filter in karate

Tags: karate

I want to remove an object from json array based on a filter, tried below code but didn't work

```
* def json = [ { "id": "0a7936ed", "code": "test", "label": "test", "type": "sell" }, { "id": "7bc1909b2", "code": "test2", "label": "test2", "type": "Buy" } ]
```

I want remove object where code is equal to test

```
* def fun = function(){ karate.remove('json', $.[?(@.code=='test')]") }
* call fun
```

Getting exception as below:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: javascript function call failed: String index out of range: -1
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFunctionCall(Script.java:1622)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.call(Script.java:1573)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.callAndUpdateConfigAndAlsoVarsIfMapReturned(Script.java:1690)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.callAndUpdateConfigAndVars(StepDefs.java:582)
```

Please suggest me how to filter it and remove the object.
Thanks inadvance..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This use-case is exactly what `karate.filter()` is designed for:

```
* def json = [ { "id": "0a7936ed", "code": "test", "label": "test", "type": "sell" }, { "id": "7bc1909b2", "code": "test2", "label": "test2", "type": "Buy" } ]
* def condition = function(x){ return x.code != 'test' }
* def filtered = karate.filter(json, condition)
* match filtered == [{ "id": "7bc1909b2", "code": "test2", "label": "test2", "type": "Buy" }]
```

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object