# How to delete multiple array objects in karate?

Tags: karate

[Here is the link to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740153/how-to-remove-an-object-from-an-jsonarray-based-on-filter-in-karate)

Taking this question to the next step will it possible to delete multiple objects at the same time which partially fulfils the condition.

```
* def json = [ { "id": "0a7936ed", "code": "test", "label": "test", "type": "sell" }, { "id": "7bc1909b2", "code": "test2", "label": "test2", "type": "Buy" }, { "id": "7bc1909b2", "code": "test2", "label": "learn", "type": "Buy" } ]
```

Means to say it should delete all the object that contains test in code i.e.

```
 code: "test" or code: "test1"
```

So will it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `karate.filter()` for this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def fun = function(x){ return x.code != 'test' && x.code != 'test1' }
* def temp = karate.filter(json, fun)
```

Comment: I mean to say will it be possible to use regex or other such thing here

Comment: If you want to delete all the records that contain 'test', you can use this code. `* def condition = function(x){ return !x.code.matches('.*test.*') }`