# Empty variable returned when tried to get selected fields from json response

Tags: karate

I am trying to get subset of fields from json response but an empty variable is returned when printed it. I know similar questions have been asked but despite looking at the solutions of those I am still not able to get the intended result.
I have following json. I am trying to get all the fields of this response except isbn with some value i.e. 9781449325862

```
{
  "isbn": "9781449325862",
  "title": "Git Pocket Guide",
  "subTitle": "A Working Introduction",
  "author": "Richard E. Silverman",
  "publish_date": "2020-06-04T08:48:39.000Z",
  "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
  "pages": 234,
  "description": "This pocket guide is the perfect on-the-job companion to Git, the distributed version control system. It provides a compact, readable introduction to Git for new users, as well as a reference to common commands and procedures for those of you with Git exp",
  "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/index.html"
}
```

- def fun = function(x){ return x.isbn == '9781449325862' }
- print result.isbn
- def result = karate.filter(result, fun)
- print result

I am getting empty result [
]

I am expecting

```
{
  "title": "Git Pocket Guide",
  "subTitle": "A Working Introduction",
  "author": "Richard E. Silverman",
  "publish_date": "2020-06-04T08:48:39.000Z",
  "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
  "pages": 234,
  "description": "This pocket guide is the perfect on-the-job companion to Git, the distributed version control system. It provides a compact, readable introduction to Git for new users, as well as a reference to common commands and procedures for those of you with Git exp",
  "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/index.html"
}
```

Here we are just removing isbn field and keeping the rest same. Please help me with karate functions

Comment: your question is not clear at all. try to edit it with an example of the **result** you are expecting

Comment: @PeterThomas please check the the expected response

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to remove `isbn` ? Easy:

```
* remove response.isbn
```

Comment: I was trying to do using js function. Is it possible?

Comment: @malyalamvenu again I don't think your question is clear. but assume the answer is no

Comment: I was trying to work on the similar lines of the solution you provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740153/how-to-remove-an-object-from-an-jsonarray-based-on-filter-in-karate. I wanted to generate json with excluding isbn which has 9781449325862 and not any isbn

Comment: @malyalamvenu ask a new question with a clear ask and simple example